# Resolving hostnames for bunch of vagrant machines

Tags: macos, vagrant

I have few decoupled components, each of these runs on separate vagrant box. What I would like to do, is giving each of these box hostname, which would be automatically resolved as domain from host and from other vagrant boxes. What is the best way to do it?

Edit:
I think the best solution would be global register of running vagrant boxes, and when one machine is up or down changes host and other machines `/etc/hosts`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The are [multiple plugins](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/wiki/Available-Vagrant-Plugins#local-domain-resolution) for this kind of functionality. Two popular plugins with different approaches are for example [landrush](https://github.com/phinze/landrush) and [vagrant-hostmanager](https://github.com/smdahlen/vagrant-hostmanager).